# I can't get the animation speed to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I'm trying to make a menu (with buttons) that open links.
when you hover on the buttons, a  slideDown reveals more information on that link.

I've gotten all those features to technically work, however i can't get the animation speed to go any slower than instantly.

I'm really new to javascript and Jquery, and it took me 2-3 days to get the javascript and CSS to do what i have so far... and yeah it's probably bloated... but i'm still proud i got this done so far :D

PS, I know most menus are made w/ul's but I really like the way the buttons look and detested trying to put the list together. last time i tried used a seperate ul for the information and it kept styling the second list like the first because it was inside it... so annoying. I also tried vertical-link list w/CSS but still think flat 'buttons' are so boring. i really like the 3D esk of the actual html

HTML:

```
 <div class="mainmenu">
    <div id="homemenu">
      <button id="home" class="mmbutton active">Home</button>
      <div id="homesub" class="sub active">-just a bit about this page</div>
    </div>

    <div id="photosmenu">
      <button id="photos" class="mmbutton">Photos</button>
      <div id="photossub" class="sub inactive">-just a bit about this page
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

javascript/jquery:

```
$(function(){
 var mmbutton = $('.mmbutton');
 var start    = "http://";
 var address  = "[my web address"; //add "http:
 var about    = "[web address]/aboutme.html";
 var id       = 0;
 var rel      = 0;
 var mmsub    = 0;
 //<click link buttons:
    $(mmbutton).click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (id === "home") {
            location.replace(start+address); 
        }else if (id === "about") {
            window.alert("I'm sorry I don't have this page set up yet. Thank you for visiting my page!");
        //add additional buttons here under 'else if'  unless its a subdomain
        }else { 
            location.replace(start+id+'.'+address);//goes to any subdomain by id
        }}); 
    //>detect hover
     $(mmbutton).hover(function(){
          id    = $(this).attr('id');
          rel   = '#'+id+'sub';
          mmsub = '#'+id+'menu';
          console.log('mouseenter'+rel);
          $(rel).removeClass('inactive');
          $(rel).stop().slideDown(500000);
     }, function(){
          console.log('mouseleave'+rel);
          $(rel).addClass('inactive');
          if ( $(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(rel).removeClass('inactive');
            console.log('this is active');
          }if ($(rel).hasClass('inactive')){
            $(rel).stop().slideUp(500000);
}});});
```

relevante CSS:

```
.inactive {
    display: none;
}
.sub {
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: the IF and else if for the links is because my links go to very different addresses, so i couldn't just use the same formula to put them together.

Comment: I have a lot of console.log() scripts so i can keep track of what is working so far. it really has helped put this together.

Comment: ah man. i didn't get 1 of the features to work again!... i want mouseleave to only activate when the mouse leaves the slideDown too.... how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it setting all that info divs to `display:none` and use `slideToggle()` function for that. Considering you want to keep the subdiv's opened when you're over them, one option is create a span element that include the button and the subdiv, and apply the hover to that span.  So...

**HTML**:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
  <div id="homemenu">
    <span class="subcontainer">
      <button id="home" class="mmbutton active">Home</button>
      <div id="homesub" class="sub">-just a bit about this page</div>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="photosmenu">
    <span class="subcontainer">
      <button id="photos" class="mmbutton">Photos</button>
      <div id="photossub" class="sub">-just a bit about this page</div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.sub {
    display: none;
    /*transition-duration: 1s; IMPORTANT: REMOVE THIS!!*/
}
```

**JQUERY**:

```
$('span.subcontainer').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div.sub').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

***IMPORTANT***: Check that to make it work you have to remove the transition style you've created for .sub divs (it interfeers with the jquery function).

***NOTE***: I don't use the `div.homemenu` or `div.photosmenu` as the containers for the hover because div's normally have some styles pre-applied by default and can interfeer with the desired behaviour (for example, they normally have width=100% so the hover applies even when you're outside of the button or subdiv in the same line). `span` is normally more innocuous to use it just as a wrapper.

I hope it helps

Comment: i dont want to do that because i want the button:hover to open a div, and hovering on the div NOT close it.

Comment: So you mean you don't want to close the div when you go out of the button?

Comment: Oh! I think I understand you. Let me see.

Comment: @Jexadox I've edited the question. Is that what you where looking for?

Comment: probably... i'm not sure how span works? and adding a period after span.... what does that mean again? why not just use '.subcontainer' ? ...man i'm so new to this i have a terrible time understanding things. I'll try it out after i save my work in separate files. your code is so much more concise than my new solution i posted below.

Comment: oh wow. thank you so much. i'll definitely look at applying <span> to things. i really like that it doesn't apply any visual changes in and of itself. i have a 1x1 px transparent picture i use to space things correctly, but i was putting it inside a <p> or <div> element that automatically put it to the font height.

Comment: Don't worry. Take it easy, man! `span`is just another html tag, but that provides no visual change by itself. `$('span.subcontainer')` just means you're selecting the `span` elements that have the class `subcontainer`. In this case will give you the same elements that `$('.subcontainer')`, because all the elements with class `.subcontainer` are spans, but I prefer to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! i got it. i was trying to do too much (show off.../ using what im learning).
I removed the line that added and removed the class 'inactive' and just toggled the SlideUp and slideDown when i wanted it too. now i can adjust the animation speed:

(HTML remains unchanged)
CSS: removed the `"transition-duration: 1s;"`
JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
 var mmbutton = $('.mmbutton');//any/all buttons
 var activebut= 0; //detect button classes
 var mmdiv    = $("div[id$='menu']");//detect button sub info

 var start    = "http://";
 var address  = "[address]/index.html"; //add "http://" + [blog or games] + address
 var about    = "http://[address]/aboutme.html";
 var id       = 0;
 var sub      = 0;
 var slidespeed= 450; //slideUP/slideDown animation speed //added var for speed

 //<click link buttons: (unchanged)
    $(mmbutton).click(function(){
      id = $(this).attr('id');
        if (id === "home") {
            location.replace(start+address); 
        }else if (id === "about") {
            location.replace(start+'[address]/aboutme/index.html')
        //add additional buttons here under 'else if'  unless its a subdomain
        }else { 
            location.replace(start+id+'.'+address);//goes to any subdomain by id
        }
    }); 
 //<hover display:
    //<detect mouse ON button
     $(mmbutton).hover(function(){
        id    = $(this).attr('id');
        sub   = '#'+id+'sub';
        activebut= $(this);                         

        if ( $(activebut).hasClass('active')) {
        }else {
            $(sub).stop().slideDown(slidespeed);
        }   
      }); 

    //<detect mouse off button AND div
    $(mmdiv).mouseleave(function(){
        if ( $(activebut).hasClass('active')) {
        }else {
            $(sub).stop().slideUp(slidespeed);
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: i really like that i can declare variables outside functions, but set them inside a function, and use that set value in a 3rd function! :)